# How to extract .7z files in Go

Tags: go, compression, unzip, 7zip, bytebuffer

I have a 7z archive of a number of .txt files. I am trying to list all the files in the archive and upload them to an s3 bucket. But I'm having trouble with extracting .7z archives on Go. To do this, I found a package `github.com/gen2brain/go-unarr` (imported as extractor) and this is what I have so far

```
        content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("sample_archive.7z")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("err: %+v", err)
        }

        a, err := extractor.NewArchiveFromMemory(content)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("err: %+v", err)
        }

        lst, _ := a.List()
        fmt.Printf("lst: %+v", last)
```

This prints a list of all the files in the archive. But this has two issues.

It reads files from local using ioutil and the input of `NewArchiveFromMemory` must be of type `[]byte`. But I can't read from local and will have to use a file from memory of type `os.file`. So I will either have to find a different method or convert the `os.file` to `[]byte`. There's another method `NewArchiveFromReader(r io.Reader)`. But this is returning an error saying `Bad File Descriptor`.

```
file, err := os.OpenFile(
    path,
    os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREATE,
    0666,
)

a, err := extractor.NewArchiveFromReader(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("ERROR: %+v", err)
}
    
lst, _ := a.List()
fmt.Printf("files: %+v\n", lst)
```

I am able to get the list of the files in the archive. And using `Extract(destinaltion_path string)`, I can also extract it to a local directory. But I want the extracted files also in `os.file` format ( ie. a list of `os.file` since there will be multiple files ).

How can I change my current code to achieve both the above targets? Is there any other library to do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. `os.File` implements the `io.Reader` interface (because it has a `Read([]byte) (int, error)` method defined), so you can use `NewArchiveFromReader(file)` without any conversions needed. You can read up on [Go interfaces](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#interfaces_and_types) for more background on why that works.
2. If you're okay with extracting to a local directory, you can do that and then read the files back in (warning, may contain typos):

```golang
func extractAndOpenAll(*extractor.Archive) ([]*os.File, error) {
  err := a.Extract("/tmp/path") // consider using ioutil.TempDir()
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  filestats, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/tmp/path")
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  # warning: all these file handles must be closed by the caller, 
  # which is why even the error case here returns the list of files.
  # if you forget, your process might leak file handles. 
  files := make([]*os.File, 0)
  for _, fs := range(filestats) {
    file, err := os.Open(fs.Name())
    if err != nil {
      return files, err
    }

    files = append(files, file)
  }

  return files, nil
}
```

It is possible to use the archived files without writing back to disk (https://github.com/gen2brain/go-unarr#read-all-entries-from-archive), but whether or not you should do that instead depends on what your next step is.

Comment: Upon trying to pass a variable of type `*os.File` to NewArchiveFromReader, I am getting `bad file descriptor` error. What is the mistake here?

Comment: @Roshan `bad file descriptor` might mean that the file has already been closed. If you want to share your code, I can help more.

Comment: I have updated the question with my code. Please have a look

Comment: @Roshan the `os.O_WRONLY` flag in OpenFile stands for "write-only", which is why trying to *read* from the file is failing. Unless you need special handling, I would just use `os.Open(path)` which will open the file for reading only.